# maven3 detect maven version for plugin - fails to activate other default profiles

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I have a need to detect if a user is using mvn2 or mvn3 in my parent pom in order to load the proper plugin version. I followed the recommendation from here : http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/maven-3.html#Using_maven-site-plugin_2.x_with_Maven_2_and_maven-site-plugin_3.x_with_Maven_3

The detection mechanism works great - however, my other profiles that are activatedByDefaul do not get picked up anymore.

Super pom look like below:

```
<profile>
    <id>profile-1</id>
    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>profile-2</id>
    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
</profile>
   <profile>
      <id>maven-3</id>
      <activation>
         <file>
         <!--  This employs that the basedir expression is only recognized by Maven 3.x (see MNG-2363) -->
            <exists>${basedir}</exists>
        </file> 
      </activation>     
      <build>
         <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
               <plugin>
                  <groupId>com.company.plugins</groupId>
                      <artifactId>my-super-plugin</artifactId>
                      <version>1.0-123</version>
                    </plugin>
            </plugins>
         </pluginManagement>
      </build>
   </profile>
 </profiles>
```

when I run mvn help:active-profiles with mvn3 --> only maven-3 profile get listed. If I use mvn2, profile-1 is rightfully listed.

**Edit ** : as it turns out, its actually well documented here : http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

> This profile will automatically be active for all builds unless another profile in the same POM is activated using one of the previously described methods. All profiles that are active by default are automatically deactivated when a profile in the POM is activated on the command line or through its activation config.

My question is now then : what work around would you recommend to have profile1 activated by default and profile 2 activated if -P profile2, while maven-3 profile activated if maven3 is used?

Answer (score 0):

So far I haven't found anything better than just:

```xml
<activation>
    <property>
        <name>!dummy</name>
    </property>
</activation>
```

where `dummy` is some kind of stupid variable name that you won't use for sure.

Comment: Well - this would have worked for my original request- I updated my original comment to fully descrive my env. I need: profile1 by default, profile2 if specified and maven-3 picked up automatically....

Comment: So I don't understand you anymore. Can you describe once again that are the scenarios and what profiles are active then?

Comment: I have 2 deploy profile: deploy by http and deploy by ssh. The deploy by http is supposed to be active by default. On top of theses 2 profiles, I have a maven-3 profile that should get activated when maven-3 is used. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yup, I think I got it. But then I can't help you and I'm really not sure if you can do this with Maven using just plain profiles. It's of course possible by using some property which activate SSH deployment, where you in fact use this property to enable/disable proper profiles, but if someone doesn't know it and uses profiles (with `-P` switch) then all this trick stops to work.